# Running Node.js App with cluster module is meaningless in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, cluster-computing

**Heroku** can run

### Web Dynos

and

### Worker Dynos

so that **Web Dynos** take care of routes

and worker **Worker Dynos** take care of processing works.

Since there is a unit of **Dyno**,

It seems using Node.js cluster module is meaningless to me on Heroku.

Because Node.js cluster module is to use all cores of server CPU

and **Dyno** seems virtual unit of CPU core to me.

Am I right? Or is it still worth to run a node.js app with cluster module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that it actually worth to use cluster module

because each **dyno** has 4 CPU cores.

---

**Reference:** http://www.quora.com/Heroku/How-powerful-is-one-Heroku-dyno

Comment: Have you done any performance tests? Is it 4 times as fast or..?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, thought I should update to a more complete answer.

According to [this table](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-concurrency#defaults) on their documentation

- 1X Dynos have 1 cluster
- 2X Dynos have 2 clusters
- PX Dynos have 12 clusters

So, assuming that you are using 1X dynos, it won't be necessary to implement clusters. If you are using the other ones, it is a good idea to do so.

The number of clusters can be found on the WEB_CONCURRENCY environment variable.

Comment: It's not X clusters, it's X cluster *workers*. You're still (probably) going to run a single cluster..

Answer (score 0):

That's very good news to me, i assumed that a dyno is just one core.
I actually wrote and open sourced a small but very nicely made cluster setup (backed by redis and job queue)

https://bitbucket.org/jeveloper/nodejscluster